# Dealing with malfromed array errors in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm getting this error :

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: malformed array literal: "["5","7"]" DETAIL: "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions
```

whenever i'm trying to store the array input result to my `postgres` database.

This the lines of code in my controller:

```php
$iitems=$request->input('parcel_items', []); 

$parcel->update(['parcel_items_sku' => $iitems]);
```

Comment: have you check `parcel_items_sku` column is json type? if your column is text, use json_encode before save

Comment: I created a column of json data type and it works fine, thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert your array to the string with `json_encode` and then save it, and when you want to use it you need to decode it with `json_decode`, that is a solution that can help you 
**So convert this**

```php
$iitems=$request->input('parcel_items', []); 
$parcel->update(['parcel_items_sku' => $iitems]);
```

**To this**

```php
$iitems=$request->input('parcel_items', []); 
$parcel->update(['parcel_items_sku' => json_encode($iitems)]);
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work for me, maybe i'm not doing it the right way. but I created a new column of json data type instead as @ZeroOne referred and it works fine.

Comment: when you want to use this way your column should be in string type